# Pointing PyGame to framebuffer on Raspberry Pi OS Lite

Tags: python, linux, pygame, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

I am writing a Python app using Pygame that will output an interface to a TFT display connected (via an adapter) to my **Raspberry Pi Zero W**'s HDMI port.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```py
import os
import sys
import pygame
import time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.platform.startswith("linux"): # So I can develop and test on platforms other than Linux without this code running
        drivers = ['directfb', 'fbcon', 'svgalib']

        found = False
        for driver in drivers:
            if not os.getenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER'):
                os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', driver)
            try:
                pygame.display.init()
            except pygame.error:
                print('Driver: {0} failed.'.format(driver))
                continue
            found = True
            break
        if not found:
            raise Exception('No suitable video driver found!')
    else:
        pygame.display.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    logo = pygame.image.load("./image.png").convert()

    screen.blit(logo, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(5)
```

The code raises one of various exceptions every time I run it with `python3`. Here are the steps I have taken before running the code (I have done nothing else):

1. Download Raspberry Pi OS from the Raspberry Pi website. I am using the [Raspberry Pi OS Lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2021-01-12/2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip) with a release date of January 11th, 2021, and kernel version: 5.4.
2. Flash the image to a micro SD card using BalenaEtcher.
3. Insert SD card and boot up Raspberry Pi with TFT display (via adapter) and wireless USB keyboard attached.
4. Use `raspi-config` to enable the serial console.
5. Connect and log in via PuTTY and a console USB cable (baud rate 115200, which is the default) to the Raspberry Pi.
6. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. Then, I install Git and generate an SSH key so that I can use a deploy key to fetch my code from GitHub.
7. Run with `python3` (or `sudo python3`, which also raises an exception).

I get the exception that I programmed into my code: `'No suitable video driver found!'`

**Can someone please explain, step by step, what I need to do after step 7 in order to have ./image.png display on the TFT for five seconds?** Also, obviously, I want to be able to continue adding to my program.

Comment: You need `root` user access to write to the framebuffer, have you tried running with `sudo` ?

Comment: @Kingsley It doesn't work with `sudo` either. Could the mistake be that I am not setting the `SDL_FBDEV` environment variable (as is done in the link above)?

Comment: If I add `os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV', '/dev/fb0')` to the top of my code, will that help?